# How can I transform full state names to abbreviations?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame **A** with a column called "states". The states are recorded by their full name, ex. "California". There are multiple rows for each state.

I have a data frame **B**, which has the number of gun deaths for each state. The states are recorded by abbreviations, ex. "CA"

What I would like is: I want each row in **A** to have the number of gun deaths for the corresponding state. I was planning to use dplyr::inner_join() for this.

But of course, the problem is that the state names are different in the different data frames.

What is the best way to make the names match?

Comment: As an aside, there are the vectors `state.abb` and `state.name` included with R which might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two vectors of the same length and want to construct a translation table just add the input vector of state names as the `names`-attribute of the output vector of state abbreviationa, and then pass in the names as inputs to the "["-function:

```
 names(state.abb) <- state.name   
 # both are in-built values in the `state`-item of default `datasets` package
 ?state     # also See: ?Constants and ?data
 dfrm$abbrev <- state.abb[dfrm$states]
```